# Remove bands below certain threshold in file

Tags: python, function, file, input

```
numberofbands = int(input("How many bands are there in the competition? "))



print("Input each band’s name pressing enter after each one") 

file = open("scores.txt","w") 
for loop in range(numberofbands): 
  name = input("\nEnter the name of the band: ") 
  votes = input("Enter how many votes that band received: ")
  file.write(name + "," + votes + "," + "\n") 
file.close() 

number_of_lines = len(open("scores.txt").readlines(  ))

def removebelowthreshold():
   threshold = int(input("Choose the threshold of scores to remove bands which are below"))


removebelowthreshold()
```

The code will take and write a band's name and score to a file.

It should then remove the band's details in the file if their score is below a certain threshold given by the user. Hope you can help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you're asking us to write the complete logic for you? It's far better if you make an attempt, and only if you can't make it work should you post a [MCVE] for us to help with.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I can interrogate the file through data = line.split(",")  and if data[1] > threshold:. However, I do not know how to remove the lines from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Why should you first write the file, and only then try to filter it? File I/O operations are the more expensive ones in you logic, so you should minimize them. You should ask for the threshold before the other inputs, and then add a condition in you file writing loop:

```
threshold = int(input("Choose the threshold of scores to remove bands which are below"))

numberofbands = int(input("How many bands are there in the competition? "))

print("Input each band’s name pressing enter after each one") 

file = open("scores.txt","w") 
for loop in range(numberofbands): 
    name = input("\nEnter the name of the band: ") 
    votes = input("Enter how many votes that band received: ")
    if int(votes) >= threshold:
        file.write(name + "," + votes + ",\n") 
file.close() 

number_of_lines = len(open("scores.txt").readlines(  ))
```

Obviously, there are multiple data type and range checks you would need to do to mke the program robust, but the basic logic is this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to print the wholes file with all the bands and then use a separate function and print the band's name and score above the threshold and remove the other ones. So your suggestion would not be possible.

Comment: In that case, generate two files - one with the full list, and another with the filtered one. Still only 2 file writes, instead of 2 file write + 1 file read in you intended method.

Comment: Sorry to be persistent, but the issue with that is that I need the user to input the threshold in the function which will be called, after making the file.